# Spell Tomes and Enchanting

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Rather than disenchanting weapons in non-modded Skyrim, is there a way to learn the spells spell tomes in a way to use them to enchant items? Ex: Using the Sparks Spell Tome to get the enchantment for 10 points of damage to magicka and health.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without mods, there is no way to learn enchantments without disenchanting an item ([source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting)); if you're looking for a specific enchantment, you can always use the following trick to re-generate a particular shopkeeper's inventory:

1. Quicksave
2. Smack them with something (dagger, sword, or what-have-you)
3. Quickload

And the inventory will be refreshed. This quickly becomes tedious if you're looking for something like Banish, however.